# Is there some way to disable "volume normalization" or "automatic volume leveling" or whatever its called?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I can't use my Ubuntu system to play anything because it keeps varying the volume from a whisper to a 747 jet engine at 3 meters distance.  The neighbors are annoyed but I dare not put headphones on lest I lose 30% of my hearing.

This occurs across not only websites but across applications including local media players.

This doesn't happen on any other operating system to which I have access:  Windows 10, Android, iPhone, OSX, etc.

I've looked at the answers provided over the last 10 to 15 years regarding pulseaudio, alsa, etc. and this ever-present problem, but the "correct" answer, assuming there is one, keeps changing with changing versions.  When I restrict searches to the last year, there is little available.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: I have the exact same problem and it's really annoying, do you use a headphone or speaker with a USB port? cause I always thought maybe that's the problem.

Comment: At present I'm using display-integrated HDMI speakers

Comment: HDMI like USB speakers transmit digital signals not analog, but most of the speakers out there are connected to sound cards with AUX which transmits analog signals, I think that is exactly why we don't find a perfect solution for this problem, probably this problem only exists for speakers with the digital signal transmission which are few.

Comment: I don't have an analog speaker to test my theory, but if you have please test and see if you still have this problem.